# Is there a percieved performance gain combining javascript defer and placing at end of body?

Tags: javascript, performance, deferred

Current coding standard seems to suggest putting included javascript -tags in the header and setting the defer attribute. This lets the html parse while the script is loading, which is good. But I was wondering whether there were further gains to be made.

With non-essential scripts, wouldn't a user on a 3G or slow network connection perceive the page as loading faster if -tag is put at the end of the  *and* defer is set, so that downloading the essential data does not have to share bandwidth with non-essential js?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the contents of the HTML page. The `<script>` content will be downloaded by the browser once the HTML parser gets to it. This means that all the HTML has already been downloaded first (1. Download, 2. Parse).

The `defer` tag will download the script contents in parallel to the HTML parsing, not in parallel to HTML download. But if the HTML contains images for example, then it would download those once it parses them, which would share bandwidth with the script if it had started downloading at the top of the page. All this would play out differently depending on the contents of your HTML and the size of your scripts, so I suggest testing it out to understand if you want to optimize for parallel downloading or parallel parsing of HTML & JavaScript.

Comment: So @leuquim, using the logics you are suggesting, there would be an advantage to place it in the footer with defer, as opposed to placing it in the header. But it will only be noticable under certain circumstances. Would that be fair to say according to you?

Comment: @ReineJohansson I think in most cases it should be fine to place it in the header, specially if you're loading a large javascript file to bootstrap your framework. That way you are starting the download as soon as possible. If you had many images to be loaded before parsing the script in the footer, it would result in a worse UX in my opinion. If your script download is really causing issues with other content or  images downloading in your HTML you can always use lazy-loading or other strategies to placehold. In any case, if it's easy to test both scenarios in your page I would do that.